# Distinguish two same private assemblies

Tags: c#, .net

I have an application that uses (has referenced) a class library  (myLib.dll  private assembly).

I created a new class library project with exactly tha same code of the first class library.

When i put in a folder the application and the second dll it throws an exception when i run it.

How does the application distinguish the two assemblies since they are not strong named?

this is the application

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            mYnameSpace.Class1 c = new mYnameSpace.Class1();
            c.test1();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

this is the code of each library

```
namespace mYnameSpace
{
  public class Class1
  {
    public void test1()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("hello");
    }
  }
}
```

It's displayed the junt in time debuger. ("an unhandled exception occured")

Comment: What is the exception? And can you clarify exactly what causes it, I don't understand your description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the assembly is not in the GAC then the CLR will search the directories in the probing paths for an executable with the same display name.  Which ever one it finds is then checked for the rest of the assembly attributes, AssemblyVersion, Culture and PublicKeyToken.  A mismatch with the reference assembly produces an exception.  I'd guess at an assembly version mismatch since culture is normally * and public key token is null.

Of course, the exception message will give you a better diagnostic than my answer.

Comment: I cant understand what is the difference between the two ddls(exept only the first is referenced). The exception is  "Could not load file or assembly 'class1, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)"

Comment: What's the Version of the original reference assembly?  Fuslogvw.exe can show you what it is looking for and what it found.

Comment: They had different assembly name (properties menu at visual studio).

Answer (score 0):

The assemblies may not be signed, but they still have their own GUIDs. Assemblies are primarily identified by their GUIDs in the GAC and not their filenames.

Namespaces are different.  If you have both assemblies referenced in your project and they share a common namespace, then the compiler will throw an ambiguity exception as it cannot determine which assembly you're trying to use.

Comment: What is it that you're trying to do? Get something to use your copied assembly instead of the original assembly? Are you trying to inject your own logic?

Also, what I meant by "share a common namespace" is that they're namespaces are the same. You should not have 2 assemblies with the same namespace and class name. If you insist on doing so, you would have to mark your class as a partial class in BOTH assemblies.

Comment: I just wanted to test how is referenced an assembly.